# grails.app.context is lost after spring security logout

Tags: spring, grails

I have an application in which I'm trying to implement external configs.  This part is working fine.  However, now it seems like some of the config settings are being lost.

I am using this setting:

```
grails.app.context = "/${appName}"
```

appName is defined in the application.properties file, and was working fine.

as stated above I extenalized my datasource and grails.serverURL settings.

Now when I click my logout link I get redirected to http://*myapplication*/[:]/j_spring_security_logout

I can replace the [:] with the context and it takes me to the correct url (post logout) but then when trying to log back into the application I get this url.

http://*myapplication*/[:] in place of the default login url.

**EDIT**
having added some println statements to my Config.groovy file.  It appears to load the Config.groovy file 3 times.  The first two times I see what I'm expecting to see, the third time is when it setts the context to [:].

Why is it loading the config three times, and what is it about the third time that is loosing my settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question.  After much debugging and hair pulling I found my answer.  It wasn't that the context was being lost after logout.  The application was never truly getting the correct settings. (in a sense).  There are several plugins that call to the config.groovy file during start up.  One of those happened to be multiTenant.  When accessing the config.groovy and subsequent external config files ${appName} was no longer in scope, thus tomcat loaded application without trouble using its default conventions.  The spring logout then tried to redirect after logout to ${appName} which at the time was an empty or [:].

The solution I found was in the external config file to change my grails.serverURL from

```
grails.serverURL = "http://myApplication.com/${appName}"
```

to

```
grails.serverURL = "http://myApplication.com" + grails.app.name
```

This allows for the application.properties file to contain the app.name variable and the external config file to use the correct property that I need for the different deployments of the war file.

It may not be the most elegant solution but it solve the issue with the spring logout.

Comment: Helped me. I did paypal config where serverUrl supposed to be changed. Make sure you set it up right for the production.